# Fortran Derived Type Operators

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading, derived-types

I am a bit confused as I am running my code to do scalar-vector multiplication using u = v * scalar and v = scalar * u

I thought the following code would give me ambiguous declaration for 
the generic '*'. How are the functions vsm_real32, vsm_real64, and
vsm_real128 not conflicting with function svm?

```
 Procedure :: vsm_real32, vsm_real64,  &
              vsm_real128 

 Procedure, Pass (tb) :: svm

 Generic :: Operator (*) => vsm_real32,   &
                vsm_real64, vsm_real128,  &
                svm

 Contains

 Function vsm_real32 (tb, sc_real32) Result (ta)
   Type (Vector) :: ta
   Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: tb
   Real (Real32), Intent (In) :: sc_real32

   Call vsmd (ta, tb, sc_real32, "*")

 End Function vsm_real32

 Function vsm_real64 (tb, sc_real64) Result (ta)
   Type (Vector) :: ta
   Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: tb
   Real (Real64), Intent (In) :: sc_real64

   Call vsmd (ta, tb, sc_real64, "*")

 End Function vsm_real64


 Function vsm_real128 (tb, sc_real128) Result (ta)
   Type (Vector) :: ta
   Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: tb
   Real (Real128), Intent (In) :: sc_real128

   Call vsmd (ta, tb, sc_real128, "*")

 End Function vsm_real128


 Function svm (sc, tb) Result (ta)
   Type (Vector) :: ta
   Class (*), Intent (In) :: sc
   Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: tb

   Call vsmd (ta, tb, sc, "*")

 End Function svm
```

Answer (score 3):

The generic binding is for an operator.  The requirement for procedures to be distinguishable is based on the position of the dummy arguments only.

(For the expression `a * b`, the first dummy argument always corresponds to `a`, the second to `b`.  Passed arguments don't influence disambiguation in this case.)

The `vsm_*` functions all have a required second dummy argument that varies in real kind from function to function.  That second argument is therefore distinguishable, therefore the `vsm_*` functions are all distinguishable.

The second argument of svm function is of type `Vector`.  This is a different type to the type of the second argument of the `vsm_*` functions (REAL), therefore the second argument is distinguishable, therefore the `svm` function is distinguishable from all of the `vsm_*` functions.

Refer F2008 C1212.